# C: Enqueue() - Inserting at the end of a linked list, returning head of list

Tags: c, insert, linked-list, queue

I'm very new to programming. Trying to write a function that receives the head of a list + the data to be inserted -- and passes back the new head of the list. I've done this a lot with adding an element to the head of a list, but for some reason I can't wrap my head around this slight difference.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_{
    int data;
    struct node_ *next;
} Queue;

int main(void){

   Queue* queue = NULL;

   queue = enqueue(queue, 1);

   assert(queue->next == NULL);
   assert(queue->data == 1);

   queue = enqueue(queue, 2);

   assert(queue->data == 1);
   assert(queue->next != NULL);
   assert(queue->next->data == 2);

   free(queue->next);
   free(queue);

   return 0;

}

Queue *enqueue(Queue *queue, int data){

    Queue *new_node, *p;

    new_node = malloc(sizeof(Queue));

    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    p = queue;

    while(p->next != NULL){
        p = p->next;
    }

    p->next = new_node;

    return ??????

}
```

I know that to insert to the head, you can:

```
new_node->data = data; 
new_node->next = queue;
return new_node;
```

Apologies if what I've written above doesn't make much sense. I'm pretty tired and I've gone through quite a few iterations. Probably missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return `queue`. You also have to test if the input `queue` is NULL, in which case you obviously can't access a `next` pointer to find the end, so in that case just return the new node.

```
Queue *enqueue(Queue *queue, int data){

    Queue *new_node, *p;

    new_node = malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if (!queue)
        return new_node;

    p = queue;
    while (p->next)
        p = p->next;
    p->next = new_node;

    return queue;
}
```

Comment: So if(queue==NULL) return new_node, right? But what about the next part? Still a little confused. Would I still need the while loop to step through the list? Once queue->next == NULL, return queue? But, er, set queue = to new_node first? *scratches head* Sorry for being dense! Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: If the queue is empty then there's no reason (of possibility) of looping through it. So just return the new node at that point. See updated answer for some code.

Comment: holy cow it worked. Hah. Trying to better understand it now. If queue = NULL, it returns new_node. I get that. If queue isn't null, it steps to the end of the list and assigns queue->next to queue. then it assigns new_node to queue->next... and returns queue. Will that work for more than 2 elements? Linked lists are making my head hurt. Thank you very much for helping ooga!

Answer (score 1):

As you are sending the head pointer, which is `queue` here you don't need to return anything.

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

typedef struct node_{
    int data;
    struct node_ *next;
} Queue;

Queue * enqueue(Queue *queue, int data){

    Queue *new_node, *p;

    new_node = malloc(sizeof(Queue));

    new_node->data = data;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    p = queue;

    while(p->next != NULL){
        p = p->next;
    }

    p->next = new_node;
    p = new_node;

    return (queue);
}

void display(Queue *queue)
{
    Queue *temp;
    for(temp=queue->next;temp!=NULL;temp=temp->next)
        printf("%d -> ",temp->data);
    printf("null \n");
}

int main(void){

    Queue *queue;
    queue = malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    queue->next = NULL;
    queue = enqueue(queue, 1);
    queue = enqueue(queue, 2);
    queue = enqueue(queue, 3);
    queue = enqueue(queue, 4);
    display(queue);
}
```

**Output**

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> null
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question! If I had to return a pointer to the header, though, how would you recommend I proceed? This is why I've been struggling so much. I'm trying to work on an optional "prelab" assignment that is supposed to help us prepare for a lab later in the week. In the assignment, the main uses assert(queue->next == NULL); and assert(queue->data == 1) after queue = enqueue(queue,1) to see if our function works properly. When I try to implement your logic, but with return p at the end, I get a segfault. I apologize for being slow! Thank you for trying!

Comment: I edited my main function to show how it really looks. It shows all the asserts now. When I try to return queue, I get a seg fault. If I change my main to have queue->next = NULL, it works, but the assertion fails at 'queue->next == ((void *)0)' failed. Aborted, it says. Not sure what's going on. On a more practical note, I THINK I get the gist of what's going on, but I'm not sure why both p->next = new_node as well as p = new_node

Comment: @AzathothM: Its great that you understood. `p->next = new_node` this will add your new node to the list and `p = new_node` will move forward `p` to next node.

Comment: You're very kind to help. I implemented ooga's logic (below) -- and it worked for 2 elements, but doesn't seem to work when I try to enqueue 3, etc. Is it possible to continue adding elements this way? Would I need to begin keeping track of both the head and the tail or? Most of the implementation that I can find with queues have a global head/tail, so it was hard for me (with my limited ability) implement the function with the restraints that I mentioned in the original post.

Comment: @AzathothM: You are welcome. In my posted code try to add more elements it will work.

Comment: Unfortunately I am still receiving a segfault with your code. It's probably (will test momentarily) because of the constraint in my main that Queue *queue = NULL (rather than queue->next = NULL)? I edited my main to show the whole main function that I had to work with.

Answer (score 0):

In `enqueue` function:

Check if the argument queue is `NULL` , this will be true for 1st time , you should handle it as a special case:

```
if (queue == NULL) 
{      
    p = new_node;
    p->next = NULL;
    return p;
}
```